# What does "for a million bucks" mean in "I wouldn't have gone inside for a million bucks"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am reading *The Catcher in the Rye* by Salinger, and I've found it difficult to interpret the phrase "for a million bucks" in the context below.

> Then a funny thing happened. When I got to the museum, all of a sudden
> I wouldn't have gone inside **for a million bucks**. It just didn't appeal to me.

This is quoted from the last paragraph of the chapter 16 in the novel.

I thought this meant Holden didn't wanna go inside because he felt as if the entrance fee was high as a million bucks. But a Japanese translation of this scene says that Holden wouldn't have wanted to enter the museum if he had gotten a million bucks.

I want to know the correct interpretation in this scene. I'd appreciate it if you would answer my question.

Comment: A museum with a million dollar entry fee is a museum that goes out of business pretty quickly.  Even the obscenely rich people who could afford that would probably opt to find something better to spend their money on.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: One could make the argument that the big art auctions are basically temporary museums with multimillion dollar entry fees, seeing as nobody is ever going to see any of that art again...

Comment: @Kevin Another good example of hyperbole! You do realize that a lot of the things you see in museums now aren't *owned* by the museum, but on loan from the actual owner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your interpretation of

> for a million bucks

to mean

> the fee was a million dollars

is not 100% *wrong*. In the following dialogue, it would indeed mean "the fee is a million dollars":

> A: What do I have to do to get inside?
> B: You **can** get inside for a million bucks.

But in the passage you've quoted, a well-known idiom is formed. It is signaled by the negated subjunctive:

> **I wouldn't have** [verb] for [price]

is an expression of

> Even if you offer me [price], I refuse to [verb].

Comment: "In this dialogue" is confusing when compared to "in the passage you've quoted" while they are supposed to mean something different. Maybe just an ambiguous 'this' in the first phrase? I assume 'this dialogue' references the phrase in isolation as shown above the comment?

Comment: @TCooper -- edited my answer to clarify. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: I would drop **have** from the template, or adjust the tense of the translation to match.

Answer (score 51):

Literally it means "I would refuse to go inside, even if you paid me a million bucks ($1000000) to go inside."

It is hyperbole. It is understood as meaning "I really didn't want to go inside".

> Mum:  Eat up your vegetables
>
> Child: They taste horrid.  I wouldn't eat them for a million bucks.

It is nothing to do with the price of the tickets for the museum.

Comment: Compare "...for all the jewels in England" or similar vast sums of wealth and riches. Contrast "can't be had for love nor money."

Comment: In the UK, we used to (maybe still do ) say 'for all the tea in China'.

Comment: It's also worth noting the drastic difference in the value of $1 million at the time of writing compared to now. Very hyperbolic.

Comment: @TCooper:  It's true that $1M then is about $10M now, but that doesn't affect the meaning.  Holden's not naming a price;  he's not saying "if you gave me $1M I wouldn't go in, but if you gave me $2M I might consider it."  He's just saying "there's practically nothing you could do persuade me to go inside."

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I still find it different in meaning. In my mind, a difference in context inevitably causes a difference in meaning. It's *more* impractical, it's *more* unlikely to be a real option. To me, currently, it's the difference between "I wouldn't do this for true, indefinite, financial freedom" versus "I wouldn't do this for a nice condo in Southern California" - while the meaning "there's practically nothing you could do persuade me to go inside." holds true, it varies *drastically* in the level of impracticality.

Comment: Yeah, but “a million dollars” has long been used as an idiom for a large hypothetical amount of money.  It's rarely adjusted for inflation, or for the exchange rate between US/Canadian/Australian/etc. dollars.  Perhaps a better hyperbole would be a *trillion* dollars, approximately the combined wealth of the 7 richest people in the world.

Comment: A billion here a billion there and soon we're talking real money.

Answer (score 8):

"I wouldn't do it for a million bucks" is an **idiom**.

"Bucks" is also **slang** for US dollars.

So it means,  **"even if I was offered a million dollars (or some other outrageously huge amount) to do it, I wouldn't."**

It is used to emphasise that the person feels very strongly, that they would not do the stated thing. Even if they were offered a huge incentive, they would refuse.

Of course like most idioms, it is used to express feeling, and not literal. Someone might say, "I wouldn't talk back to my boss for a million dollars", where in fact, if literally offered it, they would. So it is to be taken more as a manner of speech, for emotional emphasis, not literal.

## Examples:

"I wouldn't.....

- go in that haunted house
- cross that bridge
- visit North Korea
- sleep with (have sex with) some named person
- buy a house in some place
- use Windows (on a computer)
- steal from someone
- eat broccoli
- walk naked in public
- become an accountant

....for a million bucks."

Comment: I must be dumb because I've slept with some named person, bought a house in some place, used Windows, eaten broccoli, and become an accountant, and I haven't yet got a million bucks.

Comment: No.... ,you're just not that specific person who wouldn't :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you have to do all of the above